# Push notification not coming in IOS device when app in background or kill. Navigate to next screen also not working In IOS device in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, background

Push notification not coming in IOS device when app in background or destroy.
Navigate to another screen is also not working in IOS device. All things are working properly in Android device
Here is My Code::-Main.dart
https://gist.github.com/phenomenal25/87f5e9a8564b834129033c1e6e513a17

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i found the answer of this

Push Notification comes only (in IOS device) when your app in background or terminated the system tray will not give the notification when you passing custom data on this. Message is stored by FCM and delivered to app via onMessage when the app is brought back to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your info.plist, the below code is added or not.

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
 <false/>
```

Note: Test in the real device, not in the simulator.

Comment: Already added above line in info.plist and test in also doing in real device